# Trying to upload HTML file that is changed locally, apache only shows the last version

Tags: php, html, windows, apache, winscp

I am debugging code of a large-scale web application which resides on Debian and Apache.
Even though I don't have any trouble changing and uploading .php files, when it comes to a particular html file, it doesn't matter how many times I upload it, the web server keeps serving the same version of html.

Actually, I changed it once in the beginning, then after that I tried changing it, deleting and uploading it again, but nothing. When I went to the page http://[HOST]/.../thisFile.htm would show the version of thisFile.htm that I changed the first time. The weird thing is that if I open the file in the remote server (using ssh), it is indeed changed, as it was supposed to be.

To make it even more weird, my colleague tried the same thing from his mac (I use windows and winscp). He didn't have any problems changing the file. But when I changed it, the server would keep showing the last version of the htm file. My colleague could see the changes that I made when he opened the file through ssh, but not the changes to the website, unless he made the changes and uploaded the file himself.

What could be the problem in this case? It is very strange.

Comment: cached, somewhere along the line

Comment: The guys on the production server created a testing instance for us. 
Why is it that it is only cached when I change it from my windows machine, but there are no problems when changed from a mac?

Comment: could be cached in one or more of a number of places: browser,browser plug-ins, web server, router, firewall, isp ... but in the case sounds like browser

Comment: But if I make changes to the file and upload it, other people can see these changes in the file. But when they are asking for http://....thisFile.htm it's ignoring the changes. So it can't be a browser issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you are using Windows XP or older, this is likely caused by WinSCP shifting the timestamp by an hour to compensate for Windows DST "bug".

See here for details:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/timestamp#windows